# How to enable offline features on firebase_admin in Python?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-admin

Is there any other way to run offline mode in python firebase_admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Admin SDK does not support offline use for any language.  That collection libraries only expected to be used on backend systems, which are expected to always have a stable internet connection.  Offline is only supported for web and mobile clients.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline):

> Offline persistence is supported only in Android, Apple, and web apps.